Is the type of PromiseLike<T> wrong?
Here's code where the type of a promise disagrees with its resolved value:
const p: Promise<number> = Promise.resolve(1);
const q: Promise<string> = p.then<string>();
const r: string = await q;
// at this point, typeof r === 'number'

At this point, the type system says that r is a string, but the runtime behavior is that r is a number. I don't think .then<string> is a type assertion.
Is this a case where the true runtime behavior of promises (specifically in the case of no provided callback) isn't possible to express in the typescript type system?
Note: the typing of .then() is from typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts:
interface PromiseLike<T> {
    /**
     * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
     */
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>;
}


"I don't think .then is a type assertion." well no, but also you're telling the compiler what the type would be. So, not syntactically an assertion but very much does the same thing and overrides the inferred type.

Can you share the typings of .then() that you're working with? Probably the overload for the case of no provided callback isn't well-typed.

The type of Promise<T>'s then() is technically wrong as it allows you to do the wrong thing you're doing (but in practice nobody does this). The intention is to allow type arguments to be inferred, not for you to manually specify it. If you wrote then() without the type arg, it would fall back to the default and you'd get the behavior you expect. But you went ahead and specified it, so you get pathological behavior. (see next comment)

(see last comment)  It's basically ms/TS#56315. The right behavior can be expressed but it requires more complex things like overloads as shown in this playground link which bring up their own problems. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz - thank you, that fully addresses my question. Perfect. I appreciate the playground link.

@VLAZ it doesn't do the same thing as an assertion. An assertion is when you assert a type which the type system believes is wrong, with the "as" keyword. My example stayed within the bounds of what the type system thinks is right.

@LucianWischik Ah yes, it just helps to spell it out here. And as you can see, that type is indeed wrong where you can specify any type argument for the callback return type but then actually omit the optional callback value. An overload could properly represent that, like the one jcalz has shown

@LucianWischik as I said, it's not an assertion. It only overrides what the type is. You can explain what an assertion is to me all you like. Won't change the fact that you've swapped the return type from Promise<number> to Promise<string> with the code you wrote.

@VLAZ here's another angle. In a sound typesystem, runtime type exceptions can only ever occur if introduced earlier specifically by the "as" keyword. This example shows unsoundness. Even though typescript doesn't aim to be completely sound (Flow does), it's nevertheless noteworthy when unsoundness creeps into the standard library like in this case. Programmers commonly grow to trust that if they don't use the "as" keyword then they won't run into type problems.

@LucianWischik ¯\(ツ)/¯ OK, maybe if you explain to me enough your code work work as you expect. Let's see: try running it again. If it doesn't work, try explaining more to me and repeat.

You've run into microsoft/TypeScript#58619, which hasn't been declared a bug or a design limitation yet, but it doesn't look like there's much to be done here.

The then() method of Promise<T> (which is what p above is, although PromiseLike<T> is very similar) is declared in the TypeScript library to be equivalent to this:
interface Promise<T> {
  then<R1 = T, R2 = never>(
    onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => R1 | PromiseLike<R1>) | null,
    onrejected?: ((reason: any) => R2 | PromiseLike<R2>) | null
  ): Promise<R1 | R2>;
}

That's a single generic call signature which supports valid calls where the optional onfulfilled and onrejected callbacks are either both supplied, both omitted, or where onfulfilled is supplied and onrejected is rejected. The intended use of these is for the caller not to manually specify the R1 or R2 type arguments. Instead, you're supposed to just pass arguments and the compiler will infer them:
const p: Promise<number> = Promise.resolve(1);
const psb = p.then(n => "" + n, e => false);
//    ^? const psb: Promise<string | boolean>
const ps = p.then(n => "" + n);
//    ^? const ps: Promise<string>
const pn = p.then();
//    ^? const pn: Promise<number>

In psb, R1 is inferred as string from the callback and R2 is inferred as boolean from the callback, so you get Promise<string | boolean>. In ps, R1 is inferred as string from the callback. But there is no inference site for R2 because the relevant callback is omitted. Inference therefore fails and therefore falls back to the default type argument of never (that's what that T2 = never means). So you get Promise<string | never> which is just Promise<string>. And for pn, there is no inference site for R1 either. So R1 falls back to its default type argument of T, which is number. So you get Promise<number | never> which is just Promise<number>.
Those are all completely reasonable behaviors, right? If you call then() and let TypeScript infer the type arguments, then everything works well.  And this is generally how people actually do call then().

But even though that single call signature is convenient and works well to support intended use cases, it is technically wrong for the reason you found. Default type arguments can't prevent someone from manually specifying the type argument:
const q = p.then<string>(); // okay
//    ^? const q: Promise<string>

Pretty much nobody does that. But something like the following has the same problem:
const qs: Promise<string> = p.then(); // okay

because TypeScript is using the return type as a contextual type for R1 and the same basic issue occurs.

The problem is that generic defaults don't take precedence over manually specified type arguments. They're not intended to. TypeScript lacks a way to express the situation where a default function argument should constrain a corresponding type argument. This is more or less the issue at the feature requests microsoft/TypeScript#49158 and microsoft/TypeScript#56315, except they also have to do with the difficulty of safely implementing functions using generic defaults.
For now the closest you can get is to abandon generic defaults and just use overloads to spell out exactly the intended behaviors for each function argument being missing or present. Something like this would maybe work for Promise:
interface Promise<T> {
  then(onfulfilled?: null): Promise<T>;
  then<R1>(
    onfulfilled: ((value: T) => R1 | PromiseLike<R1>),
    onrejected?: null
  ): Promise<R1>;
  then<R1, R2>(
    onfulfilled: ((value: T) => R1 | PromiseLike<R1>),
    onrejected: ((reason: any) => R2 | PromiseLike<R2>)
  ): Promise<R1 | R2>;
}

Now if you call then() without any arguments, you cannot specify a type argument (the first call signature isn't even generic), so you get Promise<T>. And if you call it with one argument, you can specify R1, which must agree with onfulfilled... but you cannot specify an R2, so you get Promise<R1>.  Only if you call it with two arguments can you specify both R1 and R2, and then these must agree with the callbacks. So from a caller's point of view these are the safest way to deal with it:
const q: Promise<string> = p.then<string>(); // error

But overloads are more complicated and have caveats. Inference in the face of overloads works poorly. Changing something so fundamental to the language will probably cause way too many real world breakages to be accepted. It's almost certainly the case that the cure is worse than the disease. If they triage microsoft/TypeScript#58619, I'd expect to hear that it's a design limitation and that people should just... not call then() that way.
Playground link to code

Thank you. Great answer. My situation is that I wanted to implement .then() method on my own PromiseLike and I was at a loss what to return in the case with no callback. From your answer, I figure that I should return (value as unknown) as R1.
